# Convert UX Progress bar concept to functional CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, user-experience

I have this UX concept that I designed, I am trying to recreate this functionally with CSS and HTML, but I cant get a headstart.
I tried using Bootstrap and UIKIT but they dont allow this level of customization. Any suggestions on how to design this? Would it be a mix of html table and custom css progress bar?

[image]

Note : Not expecting any code here. Just pointers to get me started.

Comment: I'd approach it with `flexbox` but there are plenty of different ways to do it. Most important is to *try it* and then ask for help when you get stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks Bryce. I am completely new to web programming, I am a kernel/network programmer and web results gave me so many options... like CSS, Frameworks, React and so on. It felt hard to pick one that would suit. I am trying CSS, but I want to be sure thats the way. I know HTML enough, but its unclear to me how to get the text and the progress bar with vertical line as above in one flexbox. Thankyou for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean for the bars, probably the easiest way is giving a width to the container, and adding 3 elements which the sum of the widths of each one of them, will be the sum of 100%.

You could do it by giving the 3 div childs a `float: left`.

But I personally would use **display: flex.** Just add `display: flex` to the container `.progress-bar`.

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.progress-one {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
  height: 10px;
}

.progress-two {
  background-color: green;
  width: 40%;
  height: 10px
}

.progress-three {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-one"></div>
  <div class="progress-two"></div>
  <div class="progress-three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this input Mark. I will also try out flex and build up the remaining components.

Comment: Not sure what stack you're using. But with React or Vue for example, you can make it a reusable component and give it props for the width %. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @Mark, how do I draw those vertical lines with percentages on the borders of each color? Would that be CSS too?

Comment: Yeah indeed, can be possible. All the children (.progress-one...) will have `border-right: 2px solid #HEX;`. But it can be a bit tricky since those borders have more height.

But if you add the border the % would break. I would investigate `box-shadow:inset` css value, which is a border, but an inside border.